# what do you call the crust of the bread in your dialect?

Tags: british-english

We in Nottingham, call the crust of the bread the nobby. What do other dialects call it?

Comment: Unfortunately, list questions are off-topic: Stack Exchange requires each question to be inherently answerable. This question cannot have an answer which is easily accepted.